# When to use synchronized

Tags: java

I'm wondering what is the reason behind synchronizing the below code. I don't think deadlock could occur ?

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private Hashtable content = new Hashtable();

          public void deleteContent(Object key){

              synchronized(lock){
                  if(content.containsKey(key)){
                      content.remove(key);
                  }
              }
          }

          public Object getContent(Object key){

              synchronized(lock){
                  return (Object) content.get(key);
              }
          }
```

Comment: A deadlock can only occur if two (or more) locks are [attempted to be] acquired in a different order; only a single lock, or a set of locks acquired in the same order can't deadlock. See the answers as to why synchronized (in this case) is silly with a Hashtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have no idea.*

The implementation of [`Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is already synchronized and the `remove` method does nothing if the key isn't in the table. So all `synchronized` blocks can be removed (also the `containsKey` check).

---

*Maybe the `lock` is used elsewhere in the code and is there for a reason. (?)*

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficent to use a HashMap instead of a HashTable if you are already locking the operations inside the "Map-Wrapper" ?

Comment: In fact you don't even need a separate lock object.

Answer (score 3):

There is a race condition between containsKey() and remove(). A lock avoid the race condition.

However its rather pointless becasue you can just call remove() alone.

Comment: I agree there is no need for the remove() method but where is the race condition. Just one thread can access deleteContent at one time?

Comment: There is no reason any number of threads can be in the deleteContent() method. Only the synchronized block prevents those threads being inside the block concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct -- if they were to synchronize it, they should do `synchronized(content)`, which is what all `Hashtable` methods are synchronized on.

Also that cast to (Object) shows whoever wrote this has only read the cover of a Java book.

This is just as good:

```
private Hashtable content = new Hashtable();

public void deleteContent(Object key){
    content.remove(key);
}

public Object getContent(Object key){
    return content.get(key);
}
```

Comment: It's not just that it is a "self" cast, *any* object is an Object in Java -- it is redundant to cast an object to "Object" itself.

Answer (score 0):

If that hashtable is being accessed by concurrently by different methods, retrieval or deleting of elements would have to be synchronized to prevent concurrent modification!